# assigning unique default value to existing mysql table

Tags: mysql

For an existing database and existing table , I want to do something

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

however I'm planning to add a particular user_page_url with unique string. The future handling can be done through php however the recently added column will have NULL value for those old register user.

For example the ID=102 user with username="michael" will have a default value of 102 or default value of "michael"(best), then I am able to do www.test.com/michael with rewriting url to redirect visitor to his homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your new column, simply `UPDATE` your table:

```
UPDATE {TABLENAME} SET {COLUMNNAME} = username
```

Answer (score 0):

After you alter the table, do:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET NewColumn = username
WHERE NewColumn IS NULL
```